# How copy GitLab repo into Github repo without delete GitLab and Github commits?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

**Hello!**

I have create a GitLab repo from anything, it was new. But I use it and now have commits, and they was pushed.
[*New GitLab repo with his history now.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJDD6.png)

Now I would copy it into a Github repo where you have an history with commits.
[*Old Github repo with his history.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIXeo.png)

**I am trying to copy Gitlab repo and his commits into Github repo, without delete any history.**

I use GitLab mirror repo option, but it delete all history...

**Existing any command or settings to do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use git command to get all commits in local repo.

```
    git format-patch HEAD~
```

**This command are going to create one file by commit.**

You can clone your old Github repo with all old commit history. After, you just need to add all commits, file by file, with this command.

```
    git am path_of_the_file
```

**Be careful! Add new commits in the right order! Most old in first!**

*And now you have your old commit history match with the new commit history!*

[Old and new commit history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bsfp.png)

Have a nice day and good luck! I hope this answer help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can push the branch to another repo by adding another origin

On your local:

```
git checkout master
git remote add origin2 git@gitlab.com:YournewRepo.git 
git branch -m copyOf
git push origin2 copyOf
```

> EXPLANATION
>
> You checkout your branch to copy
>
> You add a new origin for your repo
>
> You create a branch copy
>
> You push the branch copy to the new repo

EDIT: as [seen in](https://gist.github.com/mariozig/bd3bb50593e6d911946b) you should be able to copy the full repo

```
mkdir mynewrepo
git init .
git clone --mirror git@your-gitlab-site.com:yourOriginalRepo.git
git push --mirror git@github.com:yourrepo
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This not work, because delete commit history from old Github repo... And change all commits by the GitLab commit history. I want to keep twice ;)

Comment: But.... You cannot merge commits between repositories because they have different head ids, etc..  You can copy a full branch whit its history, but not merge repositories...  That's because I gave you the first option of copying branch by branch... and If you later want, just merge to the branches you want and the history will be there..

Comment: Anyway, you should understand that GIT is not prepared for this, as this is not Good practices https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

Comment: I agree is not a good practice, but I have not the choice when I started because I had not authorization to copy all first repo... So I begin to work in another, in my GitLab and after, the company give me access. But thank you for you answer!